# UIButton transition

Tags: swift, uibutton, transition

I have a group of six buttons - when one is pressed (programmatically) I would like it to light up and then fade out. So I created a function called lightUp(button: `UIButton`). I also have two images for each button - lit and unlit. I can go from the default unlit to lit, but so far, trying to light the button first, before fading it back to unlit has been a problem. In the code below, the buttons don't light up at all.

```
func lightUp(button: UIButton){

    button.setImage(UIImage(named: padArrayOn[button.tag]), for: .normal)

        UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: self.padArrayOff[button.tag]), for: .normal)
        }) { (bool) in
            self.playSequence()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set two transitions, the second in the completion handler of the first perhaps?

```
 func lightUp(button: UIButton){
        UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: padArrayOn[button.tag]), for: .normal)
            }, completion: {_ in
                UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    button.setImage(UIImage(named: self.padArrayOff[button.tag]), for: .normal)
                    }, completion: { _ in
                        self.playSequence()
                    }
        )})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly you want to light up the button (maybe change the background) and then it should fade out.

You can try something like this:

```
func lightUpAndFadeOut(button: UIButton){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
        button.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

Every button calls this function and it should look like this:

```
lightUpAndFadeOut(button: sender as! UIButton)
```

Correct?

Comment: Your answer would create a similar effect to what I was looking for, so thanks! But I'm using images for my buttons so it's not quite the same.